# Outlook VSTO Add-in VB - How to read the subject line of an email opened in the inbox?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have created an add-in that allows a user to add information concerning an email into a SQL Table.

I am currently trying to implement a quality-of-life feature that will read the subject line of an opened email from the inbox into the relevant field of the user form. I have tried several methods and have had no success.

This is what I have currently:

```
Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oInspector As Outlook.Inspector

oInspector = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector()
newMail = oInspector.CurrentItem

[Initializing other parts of form]

   If oInspector Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox("No Active Inspector")
   Else
      newMail = oInspector.CurrentItem
      With AddEmailSubjectTextBox
           .Text = newMail.Subject
      End With
   End If
```

Besides the "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference" error that is thrown, I believe part of my issue is that the ActiveInspector method and CurrentItem are supposed to represent an email that is being written in a pop-up window and has yet to be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code should deal with a valid Outlook `Application` instance:

```
oInspector = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector()
```

But you are trying to call a method on a type declaration. In the VBA environment you can use the global `Application` property. For example:

```
oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
```

In VSTO based add-ins you can use the `Application` property of the `ThisAddin` class. You may also use the `Globals` namespace which gives access to the Application instance anywhere in the code of your add-in, see [Global access to objects in Office projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/global-access-to-objects-in-office-projects?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information. For VSTO add-ins the code should look like that:

```
Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oInspector As Outlook.Inspector

oInspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector()
newMail = oInspector.CurrentItem

[Initializing other parts of form]

   If oInspector Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox("No Active Inspector")
   Else
      newMail = oInspector.CurrentItem
      With AddEmailSubjectTextBox
           .Text = newMail.Subject
      End With
   End If
```

Be aware, the item opened in the inspector window can be different - appointment, task, note, document. So, it also makes sense to add a check for the item type opened in the inspector window.

Finally, if you need to get the currently selected item in the `Explorer` window, you need to use the [Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selection) property

Comment: Thank you so much! Your reference to the Selection Property is exactly what I needed!